# Can I open url on opera from console?

Tags: bash, web, url, opera

Ok, I need to open URL from console in opera (not standard browser), and can I use this command to write bash script (Ir is would be like a shortcut)?

Comment: Just call the opera executable with a url.

Comment: `opera www.google.es` should work

Comment: @m0skit0 Thanks, it works

Comment: @Evert Thanks, for answer

Comment: @m0skit0, but can I use it in script?

Comment: Anything you can type on your console works in a bash script.